# Regex Code to Allow underscore with alphanumeric not working in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I created a function to allow alphanumeric with underscore, I tried my combinations of many Regex patterns but none of them is working, I am unable to figure out what is wrong from my side. I have also written the problem I am facing with each regex expression in comments. Please find my code below:-

```
public static int ValidateName()
{
    string FileName="Test_3678";//Allowed
    //string FileName="Test.Request_3678";//Not Allowed
    int i = 0;

    string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\s?$";//Allows dot in the name, when I remove dot it doesn't allow any special character including underscore
    //string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$";//Not Allowing special characters and underscore
    //string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*";//Allowing special characters and underscore
    //string pattern = "@^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$";//Not Allowing special characters and underscore

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    bool flagFileName = false;
    flagFileName = regex.IsMatch(FileName.Trim());
    if (!flagFileName )
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What about `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

Comment: I have tried it, it is not allowing underscore also and returning i=0

Comment: I think this would be easily answered, can you give some more input (valid and invalid), i mean what about 2 underscores together? what about letters before numbers, ect ect.

Comment: can allow any number of underscores and Aplhanumeric characters

Comment: Are you looking for this ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$ ?

Comment: @viveknuna, I tried this but it is returning false with string "Test_3678"

Comment: @RahulAggarwal its working, I have tried with your code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` and dont return `int` from method, it is unnecessary. you can return the `bool`.